# undefined variable only when I didn't fill in a required field

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i'm using code igniter and I made a form with the code igniter form helper and I load 2 dropdown boxes with data from my Database and that works perfectly. And when I fill all fields in it works. I have currently 2 required fields. And 1 of them is not required. When I fill in all the required fields, it works, but from when I don't fill in one required field. It gives this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: Cities
Filename: admin/adddivelocation_view.php
Line Number: 67
```

The code on line number 67 is:

```
 echo form_dropdown('duikplaats', $Cities, '', $attributes_dropdown_gemeente);
```

I get the $cities in the view like this:

```
    function addDiveLocation()
    {
      $data['Cities'] = $this->admin_model->getCity();
      $data['Countries'] = $this->admin_model->getCountries();
      $this->is_logged_in('admin/adddivelocation_view', $data);
    }
```

My script where the values or the attributes of the 2 drop down menus change are:

```
         $('#duikplaats').change(function(){
         var data = {
            'id': $(this).val()
         }


        $.get(CI.base_url + "/admin/changeCountry", data, function(content){
            console.log(content);
            $('#duikland option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
            $('#duikland option').filter(function(){
                return $(this).val() == content;
            }).attr('selected', true);
        });

    });

    //Wanneer Land gekozen word
    $('#duikland').change(function(){
        var data = {
            'id': $(this).val()
        }

        $.get(CI.base_url + '/admin/changeCity', data, function(content){
            $('#duikplaats').empty();
            var landen = $.parseJSON(content);
            $.each(landen, function(k, v){
                $('#duikplaats').append(
                    '<option value="' + k + '">'+ v + '</option>'
                    );
            });
        });
    });
```

and the 2 functies that the jQuery function calls:
**changeCountry:**

```
function changeCountry(){

      $query = $this->admin_model->getCountry($this->input->get('id'));

      $this->output->set_output($query->FK_LandID);

    }
```

**changeCity:**

```
function changeCity(){
      $query = $this->admin_model->getCities($this->input->get('id'));

      foreach($query as $object)
      {
        $data[$object->id] =  $object->Gemeente;
      }

      $data = json_encode($data);
      $this->output->set_output($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. When I post my form it goes trough a validation function, there I load the success view when it is successfully posted or the original view when it failed. When it failed it only loaded the view but I forgot to give any data back to the view so it couldn't load the data.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says there is no $Cities variable defined. I also cannot find $Cities variable in your posted code snippets.

Either you need to define something like that $Cities = $data['Cities']; or make $data global available since you define it within a function. It is not clearly obvious from your posted code.

Does the second dropdown menue works with $Countries ?

Comment: I got the same problem with the second drop down that works with $Countries. I give it from the controller to the view via this: function `addDiveLocation()
    {
      $data['Cities'] = $this->admin_model->getCity();
      $data['Countries'] = $this->admin_model->getCountries();
      $this->is_logged_in('admin/adddivelocation_view', $data);
    }` Do you also use code igniter? BTW the is_logged_in(view, data) is just a function to see if you logged in and if yes send you to that view with that data like : `$this->load->view($view, $data);`

Comment: okay, you need to define $data public and as an array.

class MyClass extends CI_Controller {

 public $data = array();

Comment: Why? I pass it along with from the controller to the view. Do you also use code igniter?